# Having issue setting security header in vercel.json

Tags: next.js, vercel

Not sure why the docs are vague on this, but I'm trying to set security headers which is fine except when I want to allow certain domains, just not working. Getting errors in console.

```
  "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Content-Security-Policy",
          "value": "default-src 'self' *.myDomain.com; img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.stripe.com *.stripe.com https://*.split.io *.split.io; connect-src vitals.vercel-insights.com;"
        },
```

Basically, getting security errors for all the split.io items (auth.split..., sdk.split....), and for the vercel insights...

Must be a fomatting issue.....

Comment: Can you provide the exact errors you're seeing in the console?

Comment: They are they typical content blocked. I don't have them handy as I removed the security header. Buts that generic error you get when you defined the Content-Security-Policy.. i think its a formatting issue.. vercel is very vague on this.